# Probability not adding to 1

Tags: python, probability

I was wondering if I can get some help looking at the second `for` loop. In this case, the die is not fair, and I have the die weighted heavily for even numbers.  There are two issues with the code: the probabilities do not add up to 1, and the probability of the odd numbers is larger than the even numbers.

```
import random

NUM_ROLLS = 100
DIE_SIDES = [1,3,2,4,4,6]
odd_roll_result = 0
even_roll_result = 0
probability = 0

# Create the dictionary to store the results of each roll of the die.
rolls = {}

#Loop for rolling the die NUM_ROLLS times
for r in range(NUM_ROLLS):

    roll_result = random.randint(0,len(DIE_SIDES)-1) 
    if roll_result in rolls:
        # Add to the count for this number.
        rolls[roll_result] += 1    
    else:
        # Record the first roll result for this number.
        rolls[roll_result] = 1
    #print(DIE_SIDES[roll_result])

# Print how many times each number was rolled
for roll_result in range(len(DIE_SIDES)):

#    print("The number", str(roll_result).format(roll_result, DIE_SIDES[roll_result]),
#          "was rolled", str(rolls[roll_result]), "times.")
    print("The number", roll_result, DIE_SIDES[roll_result],
          "was rolled", str(rolls[roll_result]), "times.")
    if roll_result == 1 or  roll_result == 3 or roll_result == 5:
        odd_roll_result = odd_roll_result + rolls[roll_result]
        #print(odd_roll_result)
    if roll_result == 2 or  roll_result == 4 or roll_result == 6:
        even_roll_result = even_roll_result + rolls[roll_result]
        #print(even_roll_result)

probability_odd = odd_roll_result/NUM_ROLLS
th_exp = 1/6 
prob_th = abs(th_exp-probability_odd)
probability_even = even_roll_result/NUM_ROLLS

print("The probability of getting an odd number is " , probability_odd )
print("Theoretical probability of getting an odd number is " , prob_th )
print("The probability of getting an even number is " , probability_even )
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include the program's output.

Comment: `roll_result` ranges from 0 to 5 not 1 to 6 because it's the index of the table.

Comment: `DIE_SIDES = [1,3,2,4,4,6]` ?? So there really are more even numbers than odd?

Comment: You should be using `random.choice(DIE_SIDES)` not `random.randint(len(DIE_SIDES))` or you're not actually using the sides of your theoretical die

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, as other commenters have pointed out, you should fix the definition of DIE_SIDES:

```
DIE_SIDES = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Then change the line that rolls the dice like this:

```
roll_result = random.randint(1,len(DIE_SIDES))
```

Or even better:

```
roll_result = random.choice(DIE_SIDES)
```

Comment: The `randint` function includes both of its bounds, so you want `randint(1, len(DIE_SIDES))`, without the `+1`. For behavior that's more like `range` (where the upper bound is not included), use `randrange`.

Comment: @Blckknght I just checked the docs which say `Return random integers from low (inclusive) to high (exclusive).` . so my answer should be correct https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html

Comment: But the `random` module in the question is not the one you've linked to documentation for. You should read [this instead](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint).

Comment: @Blckknght thanks! nice catch! I'm too used to using numpy and didnt notice it was a different function indeed

Answer (score 1):

Your code considers `0` a roll_result, but does not count it in either `odd_roll_result` or `even_roll_result`.  This is why the probabilities do not add up to 1.

Comment: I was able to incorporate the changes and it worked like a charm....